# SSDT Publish Attempting to Drop and Create user

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

In Visual Studio 2017, I have a SQL Server Project with a simple database using SQL Authentication.

I am trying to publish a new table.  The publish script, however, is trying to drop and recreate the user I am using to publish the database.

```
GO
PRINT N'Dropping [adf]...';
GO
DROP USER [adf];
GO
PRINT N'Creating [adf]...';
GO
CREATE USER [adf] WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
REVOKE CONNECT TO [adf];
GO
PRINT N'Creating <unnamed>...';
GO
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'adf';

CREATE TABLE ....
```

I read the View Preview:

```
** Highlights
     Tables that will be rebuilt
       None
     Clustered indexes that will be dropped
       None
     Clustered indexes that will be created
       None
     Possible data issues
       None

** User actions
     Drop
       [adf] (User)
     Create
       [adf] (User)
       [staging].[square_transactions] (Table)

** Supporting actions
     Create
       Role Membership: <unnamed> (Role Membership)

Your permissions to see all objects in the server or database could not be verified.  The original error was:
The SELECT permission has not been granted on 'sys.sql_logins' for the 'master' database. You must be a member of the 'loginmanager' role to access this system view. 
Reverse Engineer will continue the import process, and logins will not be imported.
The reverse engineering operation will attempt to continue anyway, but the resulting model might be incomplete, malformed, or incorrect.
```

I added the loginmanager role to the login [adf] wondering if this would fix the dropping and creating of the [adf] user.  It did not.

Finally, I published using the server admin account.  It still drops and creates the user, but was at least able to run.

How can I resolve this issue?  I was thinking I should not use the server level admin account to do database development in SSDT/VS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Adf as login to master database also. You just need to create that login on master once. Please try the following:

---- On server level

```
CREATE LOGIN adf
    WITH PASSWORD = 'ThisIsAStrongPassword!' 
GO
```

---- Create user on Master database Level

```
CREATE USER adf
    FOR LOGIN adf
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
exec sp_addRoleMember 'dbmanager', 'adf';
exec sp_addRoleMember 'loginmanager', 'adf'
```

---- Create user on your user database

```
CREATE USER adf
    FOR LOGIN adf
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
exec sp_addRoleMember 'db_owner', 'adf';
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I solved it another way perhaps, but I will test this so you get credit!

Comment: I am glad you found a solution!

Comment: I am having possibly related issues, I asked [a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490589/ssdt-dropping-and-recreating-permissions-when-deploying-to-azure-as-database-use) about SSDT dropping and recreating permissions. Stephen would you mind sharing your solution? I tried Alberto's approach above but it doesn't solve my problem, I get the same behaviour with a db user linked to a login as with a db-authenticated user.