# SSDT dropping and recreating permissions when deploying to Azure as database user

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

We have an SSDT project which includes users, roles and permissions. It was working very nicely, but a recent move to Azure has caused, or possibly highlighted, a problem with deployment.

Before Azure, certain project members had a user on the master db with sufficient permissions to publish databases. In Azure SQL Db, there is only one admin user, and those credentials shouldn't be shared around. So instead we thought we'd use sufficiently permissioned contained database users to publish. This doesn't work for permissions granted on schemas and types.

To give an example, say we have the following in our project:

```
CREATE USER Bob;
CREATE ROLE WhatARole;
ALTER ROLE WhatARole ADD member Bob;

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoStuff
AS SELECT 1;
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.DoStuff TO WhatARole AS dbo; // <-- works fine

CREATE TYPE dbo.SomeType AS TABLE
(
     Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::dbo.SomeType TO WhatARole AS dbo; // <-- doesn't work well

CREATE SCHEMA Blah;
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::Blah TO WhatARole AS dbo; // <-- also doesn't work well
```

The problem is the publish plays up when granting permissions on schemas and types. Without there being any project changes since the last deployment, the publish script revokes permissions and then grants them again, for no apparent reason. (It was doing this on object permissions too, but we found we could prevent it by specifying `as dbo` after each grant). This adds a lot of noise and churn to each db deployment, it's something we want to avoid. And it doesn't happen if I use the Azure SQL Server admin login to publish.

Any help much appreciated. What types of users, with what permissions, do people use to publish from SSDT to Azure SQL Db, when roles and permissions are included in the project?

**UPDATE**

An example [user that authenticates at the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) used for publishing, which sees permissions on types and schemas being needlessly dropped and recreated on each publish:

```
CREATE USER OpsPerson1
    WITH PASSWORD = 'some password';
GO
ALTER ROLE db_owner add member OpsPerson1;
```

I've tried several things to try to make it work, e.g. specifying a default schema, adding the user to db_ddladmin and db_securityadmin, but no dice.

Comment: When I had permissions in the project I used post deploy scripts to do them. Alex Yates is working on cleaning up some code to generate those. Most permissions were granted to roles and I usually tried to do broad passes like schema-level when possible. Then users added or removed from roles.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSchott. We could perhaps move to post deploy scripts to handle permissions, but I really don't want to. We are using users, roles and permissions in the way you suggest, and SSDT was working perfectly at handling them declaratively, until we tried to publish using db users (which were members of db_owner, so they are sufficiently permissioned) instead of server users. But for db users we get this annoying behaviour where SSDT presumably doesn't recognise the deployed permissions, so it needlessly drops and recreates them.